# Querying Azure Table Storage with Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to query Azure Table storage without using NodeJS. If I run the query on the whole table (sales) I get all the results fine, but when I want to filter on Partition Key and RowKey I get the error "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature"

Here is my code

```
        var storageAccount = 'xxxxxxxxx';
        var accountKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

       
        
       
        
        var date = new Date();
        var UTCString = date.toUTCString();
        var dataToEncode  =  UTCString + "\n" + "/" + storageAccount + "/sales";

        var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dataToEncode, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey));
        var strSignature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

        

        var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + strSignature;

        var tableName = 'sales';
        var pk ="CAR1748"
        var rk = "1";
        
        var queryString = encodeURIComponent(tableName + "(PartitionKey='" + pk + "',RowKey='" + rk + "')");
        var path = "https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + queryString ;
        
        
      
        var header = {  "Accept" : "application/json;odata=nometadata", "x-ms-date" : UTCString , "Authorization" : auth , "x-ms-version": "2021-06-08", "DataServiceVersion": "3.0;NetFx","MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0;NetFx" };



      

        try {
            var response = https.get({
                url: path,
                headers: header
            });
            context.response.write(response.code);
        } catch (e) {
            //context.response.write(response.code);
           context.response.write(response.body);
            
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-resource-string), you would need to include the query string in your data to encode.

So your code would be something like:

```
var storageAccount = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var accountKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

var tableName = 'sales';
var pk ="CAR1748"
var rk = "1";

var date = new Date();
var UTCString = date.toUTCString();
var queryString = encodeURIComponent(tableName + "(PartitionKey='" + pk + "',RowKey='" + rk + "')");
var dataToEncode  =  UTCString + "\n" + "/" + storageAccount + "/" + queryString;

var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dataToEncode, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey));
var strSignature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

var auth = "SharedKeyLite " + storageAccount + ":" + strSignature;

var path = "https://" + storageAccount + ".table.core.windows.net/" + queryString ;

var header = {  "Accept" : "application/json;odata=nometadata", "x-ms-date" : UTCString , "Authorization" : auth , "x-ms-version": "2021-06-08", "DataServiceVersion": "3.0;NetFx","MaxDataServiceVersion": "3.0;NetFx" };

try {
    var response = https.get({
        url: path,
        headers: header
    });
    context.response.write(response.code);
} catch (e) {
    //context.response.write(response.code);
    context.response.write(response.body);
    
    return true;
}
```